# Drag&Drop at Sortable.js lists: How to set a different drop area than a Sortable list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm testing `Sortable.js` lists with this small example. I have a list of elements to be dragged from, and another list to store them by dropping the elements.

**NOTE: Sortable.js is different from JQuery-ui sortable, but the lack of Sortable.js documentation is making me consider switching to JQuery-ui Sortable, so I would accept an answer using it.**

The thing is, the drop area is the list, and it is a bit frustrating dropping over the edged of that list panel and not getting the item correctly dropped. Also, it is hard to find the list when empty if it has no borders.

[Sortable.js has an attribute named ghostClass](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable#options), and according to the documentation it should store the class name for the drop placeholder.

So I'm using the class name of the second list panel as the ghostClass for the first list. Nevertheless, it is not working, and item only get correctly dropped when over the list and not over the panel.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Fruit store</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul id="fruit-list" class="list-group">
            <li href="#" class="list-group-item" data-type="apple">Apple</li>
            <li href="#" class="list-group-item" data-type="pear">Pear</li>
            <li href="#" class="list-group-item" data-type="banana">Banana</li>
            <li href="#" class="list-group-item" data-type="watermellon">Watermellon</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary droppable-area">
    <div class="panel-heading">Shopping cart</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul id="cart-list" class="list-group">
            <li href="#" class="list-group-item" data-type="banana">Banana
                <div class="pull-right"> <span id="badge" class="badge">5</span>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li href="#" class="list-group-item" data-type="pear">Pear
                <div class="pull-right"> <span id="badge" class="badge">2</span>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Create fruit store list
var list_element = document.getElementById("fruit-list");
var fruit_list = new Sortable(list_element, {
    group: {
        name: "fruit_group",
        pull: 'clone',
        put: false
    },
    sort: false,
    ghostClass: "droppable-area",
});

// Create shopping cart list
var cart_list_element = document.getElementById("cart-list");
var cart_list = new Sortable(cart_list_element, {
    group: {
        name: "fruit_group",
        pull: true,
        put: true
    },
});
```

Any idea? [Here is a working JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/f0xearh1/1/)

Answer (score 2):

This is what the ghostClass setting does: 
When dragging an object sortablejs creates a placeholder where the item will be dropped if you let it go that instant. That placeholder will get the class set to it of the ghostClass value.

In your case:

- Remove the 'droppable-area' class name in your panel-div.
- Create css: .droppable-area { border: 1px solid black; }

Now you'll see a dashed-box of where you'll item wil end up if you'll stop dragging.

Comment: Dashed box is nicer here, replace solid with dashed.